# Login to webpage with javascript using python

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I'm new in web scraping. I'm trying to enter in a website to retrive informations using a Python script.

```
import mechanicalsoup
browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()
url = "xxx/login.php"
login_page = browser.get(url)
login_html = login_page.soup
print(login_html)
```

The results of the print is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<head>
    <title>Accesso SSO - CAS</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/cas/webjars/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css"/><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/cas/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/css/bootstrap.min.css"/><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/cas/webjars/lato/0.3.0/css/lato.min.css"/><link rel="stylesheet" href="/cas5.css"/><link rel="icon" href="/cas/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"/><script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/webjars/zxcvbn/4.3.0/zxcvbn.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/webjars/jquery/3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/webjars/jquery-ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/webjars/jquery-cookie/1.4.1-1/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script src="/cas/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.7-1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        /*<![CDATA[*/

        var trackGeoLocation = false;

        var googleAnalyticsTrackingId = null;

        if (googleAnalyticsTrackingId != null && googleAnalyticsTrackingId != '') {
            (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
                (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
                m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
            })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');

            ga('create', googleAnalyticsTrackingId, 'auto');
            ga('send', 'pageview');
        }

        /*]]>*/
    </script>
</head>

<body id="cas" class="login">
<div id="container" class="container">
    <header>
    <a id="logo" href="http://www.apereo.org" title="go to Apereo home page">Apereo</a>
    <h1>Apereo Central Authentication Service (CAS)</h1>
</header>
<div id="content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                <span class="redirect-data">
                <span id='redirectUrl'>xxxx/app/documents</span>
                <span id='execution'>591f963f-ac44-439e-bc37-65885656560b_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</span>
                </span>
<script >
/*<![CDATA[*/

    function parseURL(url) {
        var parser = document.createElement('a'),
            searchObject = {},
            queries, split, i;
        // Let the browser do the work
        parser.href = url;
        // Convert query string to object
        queries = parser.search.replace(/^\?/, '').split('&');
        for( i = 0; i < queries.length; i++ ) {
            split = queries[i].split('=');
            searchObject[split[0]] = split[1];
        }
        return {
            protocol: parser.protocol,
            host: parser.host,
            hostname: parser.hostname,
            port: parser.port,
            pathname: parser.pathname,
            search: parser.search,
            searchObject: searchObject,
            hash: parser.hash
        };
    }
    
    function post(path, params, method) {
        method = method || "post"; 

        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute("method", method);
        form.setAttribute("action", path);

        for(var key in params) {
            if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
                hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

                form.appendChild(hiddenField);
            }
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
    
    var urlParsed=parseURL($('#redirectUrl').html());
    var postParams={};
    postParams.execution=$('#execution').html();
    if ($('#errors').html()){
        postParams.errors=$('#errors').html();  
    }
    postParams.service=$('#redirectUrl').html();
    post(urlParsed.protocol+"//"+urlParsed.host+'/cas5Authn/login.php', postParams);


/*]]>*/
</script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
    <div id="copyright" class="container">
        <p>Copyright &copy; 2005&ndash;2017 Apereo, Inc.</p>
        <p>Powered by <a href="http://www.apereo.org/cas">
            Apereo Central Authentication Service
            <span>5.2.5</span>
            <span>2018-07-20T09:23:22Z</span> </a>
        </p>
    </div>
</footer>
</div>
<div><script src="/cas/webjars/headjs/1.0.3/head.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/cas/js/cas.js"></script>

<script>
head.ready(document, function () {
    if (!window.jQuery) {
        var jqueryUrl = "\/cas\/webjars\/jquery\/3.3.1\/dist\/jquery.min.js"; 
        head.load(jqueryUrl, loadjQueryUI);
    } else {
        notifyResourcesAreLoaded(resourceLoadedSuccessfully);
    }
});

function loadjQueryUI() {
    var jqueryUrl = "\/cas\/webjars\/jquery-ui\/1.12.1\/jquery-ui.min.js"; 
    head.load(jqueryUrl, loadjQueryCookies);
}

function loadjQueryCookies() {
    var jqueryUrl = "\/cas\/webjars\/jquery-cookie\/1.4.1-1\/jquery.cookie.js"; 
    head.load(jqueryUrl, notifyResourcesAreLoaded(resourceLoadedSuccessfully));
}

function notifyResourcesAreLoaded(callback) {
    if (typeof callback === "function") {
        callback();
    }
}
</script>


</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I enter in the site?
I've tried with form select "form = login_html.select("#login_form")", but it doesn't work since it uses javascript.
I'm also trying with the requests package but seems that doesn't entry in the website page.
Thanks

Comment: Thanks...Anyway, I don't need to steal data from these site, I have the access to the data, I just want a automatic way to do what I manually do...

Comment: Everyone has access to the data. It is a Web page after all.  Sorry if you were offended. I simply don't like scrapping